# Can I demand benifits that my research(performed on personal capacity) accepted in a recognized publication?

Tags: benefits, professional-development

Recently my research publication got accepted for publication in a reputed science journal. It is based on my work during my graduation and I'm a coauthor with my university supervisor. The publication has nothing to do with my role in my current employment. The entire efforts were put in on my personal capacity.

So in this scenario, Is it okay for me to demand my employer that they provide me some sort of benefits , since this publication will strengthen my position in the company as well as in the functional areas of the company's business?

If it is okay, then what is the best way for me to propose it?

PS: The employer does not have any policy in this regard.

Comment: 1) Never "demand" anything unless you're prepared to quit over it 2) Are you asking for benefits _to_ your employer (i.e. they get something) or _from_ your employer (i.e. you get something)? They are obviously completely different scenarios.

Comment: @Philip Kendall it's benefits from the employer

Comment: "The publication has nothing to do with my role in my current employment."  So what benefit does it have to your employer?  Does your publication (or the process of producing the publication) improve your productivity at work?

Comment: Even if you were polite about it (sounds instead like you're being antagonistic: "demand"), the publication changes nothing. They hired you at some point based on whatever experience, skills, etc. you had at the time. If you've done things in your non-work time to build more experience, skills, etc, company owes you nothing new. If you think you're better than the current role+comp, then push for a raise or promotion, or find a new job somewhere else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it's a publication that you've made personally, and you've not credited your employer, then it's not really clear why they would give you you any additional "benefits" (by which I assume you mean money), because it's not clear what the benefit is to them.

It sounds like what you're really getting at is that you believe that you are now worth more to them as an employee that you were before, so you want a payrise/promotion. In which case, you should ask for that through the usual channels (arrange a meeting with your manager, during the usual appraisal process, etc), and explain to them why you think that this publication means that you're more valuable *to them* (i.e, how it's going to help them make more money).

If you haven't already, it's also worth making sure that you've read your contract carefully about intellectual property rights. Some contracts will include clauses that can give the company ownership of stuff that you've done outside working hours (especially if its related to your job, which it sounds like this is). Make sure that you're 100% clear on your position before bringing it up, or you could end up getting yourself into a load of trouble.

As @Phillip Kendall says, you should only "demand" additional benefits if you're going to walk out the door if they say no.

Comment: Well, I hadn't think of these things. Thanks for the enlightenment. Now I realize, it can land me in trouble as well based on what my contract says. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> Is it okay for me to demand my employer that they provide me some sort of benefits

Not really. You did something on your own free will on your own time without your employer asking for or expressing interest it. I don't think you can "demand" anything here. However, it would be ok to "ask nicely" as long as you are prepared to accept "no" for a answer.

> since this publication will strengthen my position in the company

There you go. You already got a benefit out of it.

> as well as in the functional areas of the company's business?

That would be your leverage. The more you can put hard data around this, the better. How does your publication impact revenue, number of new clients, size of contracts, ease of attracting talent, etc.?

> If it is okay, then what is the best way for me to propose it?

Approach your management and present data on how your publication strengthens the business. Your target audience should be the people in the company to which your publication is most relevant. E.g. if you think it increases revenue talk to the sales folks.

Overall I don't think you will get a lot out of this. In my experience over the last decade or two the quantity of scientific publications has gone way up whereas the quality decreased quite a bit. Most of what I read these days is either irrelevant, extremely narrow, or poorly executed (correlation vs causation, weak reference or control variables, wishful data interpretation, questionable experimental setup, etc.) In theory the peer review process should prevent this, but in practice it doesn't.

That means the burden of proof is on you. "I have contributed to a publication" is not going to cut it. In order to reap any benefit you need to show a data driven analysis how your publication will impact the business.

Comment: Thanks. As mentioned by @Gh0stFish, I need to check if there is any conflict of interest. Even if I know that I have accomplished this work in my personal capacity without affecting  or compromising my duties at my employment, It would be difficult to prove this to my employer if at all that situation arises. If the benefits are bigger then only I can afford to get into this trouble I feel. The organizations are more interested in getting the credits of such works and it's sad.